# Как вызвать метод с атрибутом @hide из объекта?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть объект класса `AccessibilityWindowInfo`. Из [исходного кода этого класса](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityWindowInfo.java)
можно понять, что в нем присутствует метод `setRegionInScreen` с атрибутом `@hide`

```
/**
* Sets the touchable region of this window in the screen.
 *
 * @param region The window region.
 *
 * @hide
*/
public void setRegionInScreen(Region region) {
    mRegionInScreen.set(region);
}
```

Из-за этого атрибута я не могу вызвать этот метод (получаю ошибку `Unresolved reference: setRegionInScreen`)

Как я могу вызвать этот метод у своего объекта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На то он и `@hide` чтобы его не трогали.
Если уж очень надо и нет другого способа добиться желаемого - пробуйте вызывать через рефлексию. А-ля:

```java
obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setRegionInScreen", Region.class).invoke(obj, region)
```

Но будьте готовы к тому, что в других версиях ОС этого метода может не быть вообще, хотя кого этим удивишь в Андроид-зоопарке...